# datediff with convert - to show yesterdays rows - returns no rows

Tags: sql-server, datediff

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here? I thought my code look beautiful until I ran the last 2 lines for yesterday's results. the columns are there but they are empty. If I use the commmented out date line, the data shows up perfectly. This makes me think the error is in select convert statement... but I have tried every---thing.

```
SELECT RTRIM(r.acct_no) as acct_no, CONVERT(varchar,t.doc_date,101)as doc_date, t.doc_amt,
  LEFT(t.batch_no,4) as batch_no       
FROM ESUTRANH t
INNER JOIN ESUTRAND d on t.tran_id = d.tran_id
INNER JOIN ESUACCTR r on d.acct_id = r.acct_id
INNER JOIN ESUCUSTJ j on r.acct_id = j.acct_id  
WHERE (t.batch_no is null or LEN(t.batch_no) > 1)   
--AND t.doc_date between  '05/09/2017' and '05/10/2017'
  AND t.doc_date >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
  AND t.doc_date < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Comment: Your query appears logically correct. So verify that you have rows that should be included - don't assume. Try:
select top 10 * from ESUTRANH where doc_date < cast(getdate() as date) order by doc_date desc;
If that produces rows with the appropriate date, then add your joins one by one and verify.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the connection/server language settings `AND t.doc_date between '05/09/2017' and '05/10/2017'` can mean:

- doc_date between 05-September-2017 and 5-October-2017, `'DD/MM/YYYY'` format.
- doc_date between 09-May-2017 and 10-May-2017, `'MM/DD/YYYY'` format.

It's better using a date format that doesn't depend on the language configuration, like `'YYYYMMDD'`, for example `AND t.doc_date between '20170509' and '20170510'`.

Answer (score 0):

From your query,
--AND t.doc_date between  '05/09/2017' and '05/10/2017'
Above line is getting data for 1 month.

And below code is getting data for yesterday.
  AND t.doc_date >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
  AND t.doc_date < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
Can you please check whether you table has data for yesterday.